# Get data of User's XBOX account

Tags: rest, xbox

I want to extract data from a user's Xbox account. i.e. I want to extract the user's summaries/profileStats/profileStats/UserStats or whatever Xbox calls it.

**The process I followed:**

I registered an application in Azure Portal. Then on my client (Angular), I authorize the user using the following endpoint:

**[https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=${clientId}&approval_prompt=auto&response_type=code&scope=${scopes}&redirect_uri=${redirect}](https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=$%7BclientId%7D&approval_prompt=auto&response_type=code&scope=$%7Bscopes%7D&redirect_uri=$%7Bredirect%7D)**

I extract the *code* from this and then I am able to get the user's *access token*, *refresh token* and *user_id* using postman:

[image]

But I cannot find any resources to Xbox's Developer API. Thus I don't know which endpoints to call the get the User's information.

I have found OpenXBL, but it is not the official Xbox development API and I cannot figure out how to use it.

Thus what is the official Xbox Web API or can anyone provide me with an endpoint URL which to call to get a user's Xbox information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this method you will be able to extract the userName and the age group of the user's Xbox account. The other claims' meaning are unknown to me.

**Get Access_Token via code:**

After calling the endpoint in the question you will get the code.

Using the code you can get make a call to the following endpoint:
[image]

The url is: https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf

*Note: This token is not in JWT format.*

- The redirect_url should be registered in your application in Azure devops*

**Get JWT token via access_token:**

The access_token will be used to get the JWT token.

Make a call to extract the JWT token:
[image]
Endpoint: https://user.auth.xboxlive.com/user/authenticate

Headers:

x-xbl-contract-version: 1

The value of RpsTicket is "d=Your_access_token"

**Get the token claims**

Make an endpoint call to:

[image]

Endpoint: https://xsts.auth.xboxlive.com/xsts/authorize

Headers:

x-xbl-contract-version: 1

*Note: The JWT token is entered in the UserTokens array*